# windowsPhone: unknown type 'LoginButton' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-login

I have included nuget facebook package and facebook client package then also it shows me the following error 
"unknown type 'LoginButton' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"

Below is my Code

```
<Page
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:facebookControls="clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"

        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

        <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock FontSize="48" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Text="welcome"/>
            </Grid>

            <!--user information-->
            <StackPanel 
               Grid.Row="2" 
               Orientation="Horizontal" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="5">
                <TextBlock 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Name, ElementName=loginButton}" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- login control -->
            <facebookControls:LoginButton 
                x:Name="loginButton" 
                Grid.Row="2" 
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                SessionStateChanged="OnSessionStateChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

Comment: You need to reference Facebook.Client.dll and make sure there is a type Facebook.Client.Controls.LoginButton.

Comment: i have included all the needed stuff

Answer (score 1):

replace
xmlns:facebookControls="clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"

for
xmlns:facebookControls="using:Facebook.Client.Controls"

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had exactly the same problem. The documentation did specify that you also have to complete this tutorial in order to make the control work:
For Windows Phone 8.1 and Universal Apps you should use this tutorial:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/
For Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight tutorial you should use this one:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/

Also i found out that, if you only install facebook.client from nuget in windows phone 8.1 app, nuget cannot resolve dependency for facebook package. So just first install "facebook" package, then add "facebook.client".

Please let me know, if it worked - if no, please specify more info.

Also please notice, that the control doesn't render anything in design view - it only draws a button on runtime - maybe I still have something misconfigured.